# Hand gets shaky while aiming in CSGO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've been playing shooters (mostly TF2 and PUBG recently) for 5 years now, and have been trying to get into Counter Strike. But whenever I practice my aim or play competitive, I have this strange thing that happens: I move my crosshair near the target, and when I try to adjust my aim, my hand just tenses up and freezes, getting shaky and I can't properly adjust my aim. It's especially bad when spraying, it takes physical effort to move my hand.

Have any of you ever had something similar? If so, how did you get past it? Can I practice in some specific way to get rid of this? (It's not anything medical btw).

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you unable to adjust the mouse itself or is the crosshair shaking around while not even moving the mouse? Can you move the mouse just fine in let's say MSPaint and draw something without getting shaky? Is it even a gaming mouse?

Comment: I'd love to know why you think "it's not anything medical".

Comment: What is your mouse sensitivity and DPI?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a case of the 'yips', its a super bad issue with professional golfers. 
[Being unable to make a nice smooth movement your body tenses up and has uncontrollable shakes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yips)
.

What they do in golf is try to isolate whats causing it and change that (swapping hands,, the claw).

You should try switching to being and "arm" aimer.  Where your wrist and hand are always in the same position and you move the mouse around with your shoulder and elbow, instead of your wrist.

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hcuCrGqEFhk)

Answer (score -2):

Probably you just need to practice more, there are a lot of workshop maps that help you to control you aim/spray.